# At the end of Hop, does Fred also poop jelly beans?

Tags: hop-movie

In the film *Hop* the Easter Bunny (E.B.) freaks Fred out by pooing out a mound of jelly beans. This was explained as being something E.B. does.

At the end Fred and E.B. are made "co-Easter Bunnies". So does Fred also now excrete candy?

Comment: SFF. Asking the serious questions.

Comment: So were these all black jelly beans?

Comment: @Peter M nope, multi coloured. What makes you think all black? Was Fred from New Zealand?https://goo.gl/images/SwTC2B

Comment: @Danny3414 That would be *all blacks* jelly beans, not *all black* jelly beans if Fred was a Kiwi.  However natural rabbits poop black, jelly bean sized pellets.  But in regards to your pic - is black even in the color pallet of jelly beans in the movie?

Comment: Not a proper SE question but it relates to mine about excreting jelly beans. I have five grandkids, three of these are old enough to comprehend 'Hop' and, since watching it, none will eat jelly beans, the thought revolts them. Has anyone else had this in their families? (Another question...is there any record of a slump in jelly bean consumption since Hop was released?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked my good friend [Cinco Paul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinco_Paul_and_Ken_Daurio) (co-writer of the film's screenplay) this question. He confirmed that now that he's an Easter Bunny, Fred does indeed excrete jelly beans.

> **Q.** *Quick (and more than slightly random) question. At the end of Hop, does Fred also start to poop jelly beans? Is it an Easter Bunny thing?*
>
> **Cinco Paul: *Most definitely.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/cincopedia/status/1016830629453762560)</sup></sub>